# Dealing with new line character in rails form_for text_area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, simple-form-for

What is best practice for dealing with new line characters in text_area within form_for?

I noticed `\r\n` is how it is represented. I believe that is a carriage return (a new line that will be recognised on all operating systems).

Can this cause issues? Is it better practice to substitute it for `\n` which is what many programmers would consider the correct representation of a new line?

My reason for asking is simply to ensure I don't create problems later down the track that could have been averted with some foresight and inquisition.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398145/10067393